# An abstract integration problem from a mathematical finance calibration problem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I would massively appreciate help on this problem which relates to me trying to calibrate my financial model to market data. It can be stated without reference to any finance, this is my abstract statement of the problem:

We are given a function f:[0,$\infty$) -> [0,$\infty$) and a function p: [0,$\infty$) $\times$ (-$\infty$,$\infty$) -> [0,$\infty$).

What restrictions can we put on a function $\pi(\cdot)$ that maps (-$\infty$,$\infty$) -> [0,$\infty$) such that the following holds $\forall t \geq 0$:

$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(t,x) \pi(x) dx $      ?

It seems to me, in principle at least, that we should be determine $\pi(\cdot)$ uniquely in terms of $p(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ because we have a full dimension of freedom (we can set $\pi(x)$ to any level we like for every $x$) and we have a full dimension of constraints (the integral must equal the value given by $f(t)$ for every t). I don't think it's of relevance, but let me also mention that $p(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a density function for any given t, i.e.

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(t,x) dx = 1 $    $(\forall t \geq 0)$.

Comment: We need to add further assumptions for sure. Else, if $f$ is non-constant, and $p(t,x)$ depends only on $x$, then the problem as stated clearly has no solution.

Comment: Yes, but I guess there could be a general solution which reflects these sorts of cases, for example it could have the partial derivative of p w.r.t t in the denominator. To add to the mix: there is a famous finance equation called the Breeden-Litzenberger equation which is a special case of my problem: $f(t) = \int (x-t)^{+} p(x) dx$ -> $f''(t)=p(t)$.

Comment: As a toy model, think of $f\in \mathbb R^n$, a matrix $P$, and replace the integral by matrix multiplication. Even in this simplified case you get *necessary* conditions.

Comment: Thanks Jochen, I will think about that. Since I posted I've found that this problem has been studied in more generality the area of Fredholm theory (there is a good but brief wikipedia page). I will post anything I find from there.